# How do I add structured content to a Word Document via Interop (C#)?

Tags: c#, ms-word, ms-office, vsto, office-interop

Thanks for looking. I am writing some C# to create a word doc based on a dataset. Using `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word` I am able to create a document with *formatted* headings for the sections, but there is no associated structure. In other words, I can't see my sections in the Navigation pane or generate a Table of Contents.

Here is what I am trying:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application WordApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document document = WordApp.Documents.Add(ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);

document.Range(0, 0);

foreach (var solutionModel in solutions)
{
    var hText = document.Paragraphs.Add();
    hText.Format.SpaceAfter = 10f;
    hText.set_Style(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdBuiltinStyle.wdStyleHeading1);
    hText.Range.Text = solutionModel.Name;
    hText.Range.InsertParagraphAfter();

    var pText = document.Paragraphs.Add();
    pText.Format.SpaceAfter = 50f;
    pText.set_Style(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdBuiltinStyle.wdStyleNormal);
    pText.Range.Text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.";
    pText.Range.InsertParagraphAfter();
}

WordApp.Visible = true;
```

This renders nicely in Word with the headings (`hText`) taking on the native Header 1 style, but there is no associated structure.

Comment: This could also be a refresh problem. Save your newly created document, close Word and then open the document again. Does the *Navigation Pane* now show the structure of your document?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the OutlineLevel (that is located on the ParagrapFormat of a Paragraph's Range) to the desired level (VBA):

```
ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(1).Range.ParagraphFormat.OutlineLevel = wdOutlineLevel1
```

In your case (C#):

```
hText.Range.Text = solutionModel.Name;
hText.Range.ParagraphFormat.OutlineLevel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdOutlineLevel.wdOutlineLevel1;
```

This will add the selected paragraph to the Navigation View

Comment: +1 This may indeed be the problem here. Just for the record: If the built-in heading styles are not modified, then the outline level should already be correct (i.e. *Heading 1* has outline level 1, *Heading 2* has outline level 2 etc.)

Comment: This is what I initially thought too @DirkVollmar and was quite surprised to find that (like @Matthew) I found that it didn't work properly. Doing some more research on it I found that setting the text after applying the style setting was lost. By moving setting the text before applying the style seemed to solve the issue (see my other answler).

Answer (score 2):

Initially I was thinking the same as @Dirk mentioned in the comments, but tested it and as you've seen yourself that didn't work in your code.

After doing some more research I found that my other answer actually did not result in having the right Header Style applied to your added paragraphs. So my testing resulted in the following outcome:

You need to set the text **before** applying the style.

```
var hText = document.Paragraphs.Add();

hText.Range.Text = solutionModel.Name; // <--

hText.set_Style(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdBuiltinStyle.wdStyleHeading1);
hText.Format.SpaceAfter = 10f;
hText.Range.InsertParagraphAfter();
```

I added two empty rows to bring attention to the position of the Text line location, but you can leave that out.

Comment: Indeed, and also setting the `SpaceAfter` should happen *after* setting the `Style`.

Comment: Right, otherwise the Heading style reverts the changed SpaceAfter.

Comment: Thanks, yes--the order in which the text was set is critical. I set both the outline level and the style afterwards and all worked. Thanks agian.